# Login via Java Webapp

Tags: java, http, web-applications

I already asked this question, but because of missing answers i'll give it another try!

#### What i want to do

Write a java webapp which logs me, automatically, in any webapp. For an example I chose my zimbra
mailaccount.

#### How should my Java webapp work

the app should send a login request to the particular app, which is usually corresponding to 
the action in the login-form. After executing my app cookies should be set so that I'm logged in
automatically.

#### What I'm currently trying

I'm using the code below, the `doGet()` method is part of an extended `HttpServlet`.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

    PostMethod postMethod1 = new PostMethod("http://mail.mydomain.at/zimbra/");
    postMethod1.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
    postMethod1.addParameter("username", "myname@mydomain.at");
    postMethod1.addParameter("password", "mypassword");
    postMethod1.addParameter("loginOp", "login");
    httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod1);

    out.println(postMethod1.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

#### What's the problem

After executing the code I only get a message, saying that my browser(which is in fact my HttpClient) appears to prohibit cookies.

So what, I think, happens is that the cookies are going to be set in the `HttpClient`, which I initialized.
But what i want to happen is that the cookies are set in my browser. How can i accomplish this?

SOLUTION:
the quest failed, because by logging in with a webapplication (via a self instantiated HTTPClient), this client receives the cookies, but not the browser. No workaround was found.

Comment: So after executing this *Java code* you want **your browser** to be logged in? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, thats correct.
to explain the purpose of this app: i'm trying to build a rudimentary single-sign on app

Comment: In that case you will have to directly manipulate your browsers cookies which may not be as trivial as you hope. It's possibly easier to write this as a browser add-on (or a GreaseMonkey/User script).

Comment: If you want single sign on, you are better off implementing that on your own, where a user logs onto "your" system and then you retrieve the user name and password, the cookie, whatever to pass to the system they want to connect to. Not trivial by any means though.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. a browser-addon is not browser independent, which i would prefer by far. and if not a own implementation of handling user accounts and cookies...what else? there has to be a technical possibility to implement an automated/centralized login!?

Comment: to suggest another solution: would it be possible to implement a rudimentary browser (within my java webapp) which holds the cookies and delegates all requests/responses between the browser and a selection of webapps!?

Comment: @mposch, yes, you can simulate browser behavior within your java code, but if the site you want to integrate with has some public API I would rather use that.

Comment: @Andrey, i also thought about using a public API, but zimbra for example offers a very restricted API, so all i can do is getting the mail folders and my contacts. so there's is no service for e.g. sending a mail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can set a cookie of www.xyz.com domain if your browser is accessing www.abc.com. Otherwise it would be a big security violation. Anybody could set a fake cookie in their browser and access your data.

In your case you will need to excpilitly login to zimbra from your browser in order to get the cookie set on the client.

Comment: you're right, setting a cookie for a foreign domain is not possible! with "explicitly" you mean manually?

Comment: yes, it should be you who log in to zimra site from within your browser in order for the browser to create a cookie that log you in automatically when you return to the site. But still that coockie will not be available to other domains in any way. if you want integration it should happen in backend.

Comment: the reason why i wanted an integration in frontend was, that i wanted to use the GUI of the target webapplication...don't know whether this makes sense ;)